# Three.js MeshlambertMaterial example not visible/does not work in one computer

Tags: three.js

I have two computers

1. Windows XP 32 + chrome last version
2. Windows 7 home Premium 64 bits + chrome last version

The meshlambertmaterial example is not showing at PC 2?

I have discover that there is some problem related with the lights or the emissive color ( initially black, and screen black = nothing is viewed.) I can see the 3D object if I choose other color but the result is poor because the light is not taken into acount. The behaviour is like meshbasicmaterial.

The phong material, depht and others works as expected.

I promise I'm using the web example http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshLambertMaterial

Same problem with Firefox last v.

Any idea what is happening? It is related with my graphic card? Windows 7 
Other materials (phong) are viewed OK.

Any tool to check what is happening?

**UPDATED**

The problem could be related with three.js release.
This example uses three.js r60 :

http://www.lostmarble.com/misc/experiments/learning-threejs-master/chapter-04/06-mesh-lambert-material.html

This example works fine on my 'problematic' second computer.
However, if I change the src to three.js r71, the box is black ?

The example uses ambient white color but this parameter does not exist in r71
Any idea Westlangley? (I know that this is strange but .... is a real problem)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the second example is opened by file. If opened from the link you posted that holds the example is the same problem taking place?
Also the background of the file is black so the setClearColor attribute of the renderer might be set wrong. The black box can be related with the light.Can you post some code?

I would advise you always to use the latest revision of three js if possible.

Comment: The examples are  the http://www.lostmarble.com/misc/experiments/learning-threejs-master/chapter-04/06-mesh-lambert-material.html, the 'file' example is the original but with three.js r71 version. As I said, first example (three v60) shows lambertmaterial but second (v71) doesn't. Same using firefox.

Comment: @westlangley, any idea ? Is a three.js problem or a windows 7 problem ?Where could I see what ?